# Add Quick Feature Image Option In quick Edit (Wordpress - Woocommerce)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOXka.jpg

I want add Featured Image Option In Quick Edit Please Share a tutorial or a code

Answer (score 2):

there's a plugin for that : 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/featured-image-admin-thumb-fiat/

no need to write it yourself.

Comment: Okie Let Me check

Comment: Its Only Working On Pages and Post Not In Products

Comment: After checking that the plugin is enabled, be sure to click Screen Options if you don’t immediately see the column and ensure “Thumb” has a checkmark next to it

Comment: Yeah I check this too but there is no option of thumbs in products page

Comment: funny - i am litterally using it right now :) I just check "Featured image" in the screen settings on my products page

Comment: In Quick Edit ? i have 300+ product and i have to change featured images of all product i want to do in short time so if there is any plugin that give a option of changing feature image in quick edit so i can change the image fast as i can i don't want to open each product .

Comment: and please send a screen shot of your page too

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you mean, I don't know any ready plugins for it, but I think it can be implemented with the following steps:

1. Add a Posts/Products column
2. Enqueue the WordPress uploader script
3. Create the function that will run the uploader in JavaScript/jQuery
4. Add quick edit option with default `_thumbnail_id` name attribute because in this case `save_post` action isn't required
5. Populate the Quick Edit values with JavaScript

This is just a step by step algorithm, you asked about a tutorial, please look at this https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/quick-edit-featured-image.html

Comment: thanks for your comment bro but i got a plugin for that :)